# Python stopped working after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, python

I upgraded my Mac from Lion to Mountain Lion and ever since then, Python stopped working.
So I re-installed Python and his setup-tools. Now everything seems to work fine except for iPython. iPython requires readline, which in his turn requires the Mac OSX 10.6 SDK.

How can I install the MacOSX 10.6 SDK in my current confuguration (Mountain-Lion)?
Or is there an alternative solution to get things working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOSX SDK 10.6 is a component of Xcode. It is at least available in Xcode version 3.2.6.

Xcode is available for download from Apple after registration as a software developer.

The file is named MacOSX10.6.pkg and is located in the /Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Packages folder.